# Can I use spam and RA flags interchangeably?

Tags: support, flags, spam, offensive, trolling

If I flag trolling as spam, or flag spam as rude or abusive, will that be a big deal? Sometimes I come across a malicious post but at first glance I can't tell whether it's spam or trolling. In that case, should I flag it as either and move on, or spend time trying to determine whether it is spam, or whether it is offensive or trolling and flag it appropriately?

If they can be used interchangeably, why are they distinct flags?

Comment: Isn’t this explained in [What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/289905)?

Comment: We would prefer that you *try* to use them based on what the labels say. But in cases where you can't readily tell which is which, it's OK to just pick one.

Comment: @CodyGray Ok, thanks for clarifying